# Linq grouping with list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, grouping

I have an entity like this

```
Product                           Room
long productid                    long roomid
List<Room> rooms                  string roomname
String name
```

Now I have a list of Product entities which has duplicate date apart from list of rooms.
Eq.

```
Product                                
Id 1                        Id2                    Id3
Rooms = 1,A                 Rooms = 1,B            Rooms =1,C
ABC                         ABC                    ABC
```

In this case I have the same property repeated 3 times because it got 3 rooms.

What I am trying to do is add all the rooms to one Product entity which will have one product entity and list of rooms (list of 3 in this case).
I tried something like this but it doesn’t work.

here I am passing the property id

```
var result = from t in Product
             where t.ProductId == propId
             group t by t.Rooms
             into g
             select g;
```

Any help or idea please

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: @RiskyMartin: As i mentioned in the question, one property will not repeated. It will display as a one property but with list of rooms in it

Comment: So do you want the product whose ID is `propId`, with the rooms from all products, even if the products' IDs are not `propId`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var product = Product.First(p => p.ProductId == propId);

product.Rooms = from p in Product
                from r in p.Rooms
                select r;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get the list of rooms that are associated with any of the products, you could try this:

```
var query = from t in products
            select t;
var rooms = query.Aggregate(new List<Room> { }.AsEnumerable(), (i, p) => i.Union(p.rooms));
```

Note that the aggregation will NOT be executed as an sql query (if you are pulling data out of a db) - rather, it will be performed in memory.

I'm not sure if this is the result you wanted, but it will get you a list of rooms that are in the "rooms" property of all of the products combined. For example, if you have one product with rooms "A" and "B", and another product with "C", the resulting list of rooms will contain "A", "B", and "C".